# Create Function: Syntax Error at or near $$

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I'm a beginner in Postgres and I want to automate dropping a column from a table with a function. But it gives me the error I mentioned in the title.

Here's my code:

```
create function dropColumn(table_name text,col_name text) returns void as $$
ALTER TABLE $1 DROP COLUMN IF EXIST $2;
$$
language 'psql';
```

Error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$$
> language 'psql';
> create function dropColumn(table_name text,col_name text) returns
> void $$"
> LINE 1: $$
> ```

What's the problem? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple problems. Most importantly, you cannot parameterize identifiers in plain SQL (or *anything* in DDL commands, for that matter). You need dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE` in a PL/pgSQL function. This would do the job:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION drop_column(table_name text, col_name text)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %I DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS %I'
                 , table_name, col_name);
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT drop_column('my_tbl', 'my_column');
```

Read the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html), and study some [related questions and answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplpgsql%5D%20%5Bdynamic-sql%5D%20code%3ACREATE):

Pay special attention to defend against SQL injection properly:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I'm going to try this solution and then go through the links you as you've suggested.

Answer (score -2):

You forgot the keyword `AS`:

```
create function dropColumn(table_name text,col_name text) returns void AS $$
ALTER TABLE $1 DROP COLUMN IF EXIST $2;
$$
language 'psql';
```

Comment: No, please double-check, the syntax is OK this way.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I just copied the code you wrote but still it gives error.I will restart my terminal and try again.

Comment: It now says language 'psql' doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, this is not a standard language, you should use `sql`

Comment: But there were other functions that I wrote using this phrase?

Comment: `sql` and `plpgsql` are standard languages for postgresql stored procedures. I do not know `psql` in that context (except that the cli-tool has that name). Does it work with `sql`?

Comment: I tried with sql it gave me the error :

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 2: ALTER TABLE $1 DROP COLUMN IF EXIST $2;
                    ^

Comment: That's a different story: You cannot use a table/column name from a variable. Better use `plpgsql`, build the query string and use `execute`

Comment: This answer is almost as completely wrong as the question. There is no language 'psql' to begin with. And you cannot parameterize identifiers in plain SQL statements *at all*. You need dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE` in plpgsql for this ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter The primary question was about the syntax error, which I addressed. Secondly, it would be perfectly possible to create a language `psql` which works as the OP expected. This was out of the scope of this question. Please inform yourself a bit better about postgresql before teaching others. Thanks.